# Java 11 Select a method to apply on a stream based on enum value

Tags: java, enums, stream, java-stream, java-11

I have the following enum.

```
public enum AggregationType
{
    MIN,
    MAX,
    AVERAGE
}
```

let's assume that i have a function where i pass enum value like

```
public Float someFunction(final AggregationType enum) {
            return (float) provides.stream()
                                      .mapToDouble(this::someFunc)
                                      .average()
                                      .orElse(-1);
        

}
```

I want to apply this .average() .min() .max() methods on a stream based on enum value.

How i can achieve this? I don't want to use simply switch function inside someFunction but rather in this return statement.

So i want to have something like

```
public Float someFunction(final AggregationType enum) {
            return (float) provides.stream()
                                      .mapToDouble(this::someFunc)
                                      .decideWhichMethodShouldBeUsed()
                                      .orElse(-1);


}
```

where  decideWhichMethodShouldBeUsed()
decides which func to use based on enum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you can change the `enum` type to

```java
public enum AggregationType {
    MIN(DoubleStream::min),
    MAX(DoubleStream::max),
    AVERAGE(DoubleStream::average);

    public final Function<DoubleStream, OptionalDouble> operation;

    AggregationType(Function<DoubleStream, OptionalDouble> f) {
        operation = f;
    }
}
```

you can implement the method like

```java
public Float someFunction(final AggregationType aType) {
    return (float)aType.operation.apply(provides.stream().mapToDouble(this::someFunc))
        .orElse(-1);
}
```

If changing the enum type is not an option, you have to handle the mapping to the actual operation at the place where you want to implement `someFunction`, e.g.

```java
private static final Map<AggregationType,Function<DoubleStream, OptionalDouble>> OPS;
static {
    EnumMap<AggregationType,Function<DoubleStream, OptionalDouble>>
        m = new EnumMap<>(AggregationType.class);
    m.put(AggregationType.MIN, DoubleStream::min);
    m.put(AggregationType.MAX, DoubleStream::max);
    m.put(AggregationType.AVERAGE, DoubleStream::average);
    OPS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
}

public Float someFunction(final AggregationType aType) {
    return (float)OPS.get(aType).apply(provides.stream().mapToDouble(this::someFunc))
        .orElse(-1);
}
```

---

You can also use a `switch` statement, but it’s rather clunky

```java
public Float someFunction(final AggregationType aType) {
    DoubleStream ds = provides.stream().mapToDouble(this::someFunc);
    OptionalDouble d;
    switch(aType) {
        case MAX: d = ds.max(); break;
        case MIN: d = ds.min(); break;
        case AVERAGE: d = ds.average(); break;
        default: throw new AssertionError();
    }
    return (float)d.orElse(-1);
}
```

Things get better when you’re using a recent Java version, as then, you can use a `switch` expression:

```java
public Float someFunction(final AggregationType aType) {
    DoubleStream ds = provides.stream().mapToDouble(this::someFunc);
    return (float)(switch(aType) {
        case MAX -> ds.max();
        case MIN -> ds.min();
        case AVERAGE -> ds.average();
    }).orElse(-1);
}
```

This is only accepted by the compiler when all `enum` constants are handled. Then, it will generate an equivalent to `default -> throw new AssertionError();` behind the scenes which will never be taken at runtime, as long as no-one changes the `enum` type after this code has been compiled.

Generally, only the first variant forces developers who consider adding new constants to `AggregationType` to also also consider handling the associated `operation`.

Comment: This is the kind of use case for which I always thought `Stream` should have a `<U> U andThen(Function<Stream<? extends T>, U> transformer)` (and equivalent for streams of primitives) which would just be implemented as `return transformer.apply(this)`. It would allow to write `provides.stream().mapToDouble(this::someFunc).andThen(aType.operation).orElse(-1)`, which would be much more fluent than the `aType.operation.apply()` version.

Comment: @DidierL indeed. For most operations on a `Stream` we could construct such operation using `collect`, but for a `DoubleStream`, this would have too many drawbacks. Such an operation could be even added as `default` method of `BaseStream`, just three lines of code for a working solution for all stream types…

Comment: Adding it on `BaseStream` would be brilliant! I think even for streams of objects it would be useful because it would allow keeping the laziness when the `Function` is just calling some intermediate operation(s) on the stream.

Comment: I have noticed however that some people dislike passing `Stream` as parameter as they fear you wouldn’t be sure whether the stream would be consumed by the method (although I think it’s a good assumption to take in such a case!). Apart from that I didn’t find strong arguments against doing it (in any case, this `andThen()` wouldn’t fix that, but it would somewhat show approval from the Java designers).

Comment: I just found there is already [JDK-8140283: _add Stream::transform method to facilitate fluent chaining of other methods_](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8140283) for my idea.